# How to delete random elements with RandomChoice?

Tags: list-manipulation, warning-messages

I have a list of prices and a list of dates, but I have 154 more prices than dates. So I want to delete random prices to match both lists, however, every time I run the block of code I get a different length for the final list. I don't understand where is the error or another way to match both lists.

[image]

Second run, why I get a different length when I supposedly deleted 154 again?

[image]

At first I tried

```
FixBVP=DeleteCases[BVPclean,Alternatives@@deleterandomBVP]
```

But I still get different lengths.

Comment: (1) Use `RandomSample` instead of `RandomChoice` and (2) reset the random number generator using the same seed (e.g.,  `SeedRandom[1]`) before each of the two code blocks.